# Check if Wifi Is Turned On While App is Active

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, reachability

I have an app using Reachability library to detect when wifi is turned on while the app is active. I have the following code sample below in my view controller. The view controller is loaded when the app becomes active. When I run this code on my iPhone the selector method is not called. What's wrong with this code and how do I fix it?

```
let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("view did load")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name:  "ReachabilityChangedNotification", object: reachability)

    reachability.startNotifier()
}

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

    // I don't see this line printed out!!!
    println("selector method called")

    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.isReachable() {
        println("yay internet is on")

    } else {
        println("internet is off")
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but I do see where you call "reachabilityChanged" in the ViewDidLoad. But if it is called from the reachability library. Maybe try calling "reachability.startNotifier()" from viewWillAppear".  Also if you remove "note: NSNotification" does the function fire at all?

Comment: Sorry, neither of those things did it for me. The function does not fire in either case.

Comment: where are you sending the NSNotification? If you removed "note: NSNotification" and nothing fired. Then you need to verify that where ever you send the NSNotification, is actually sending it correctly.